# Algorithm analysis - when to throw away terms?

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, computational-complexity, analysis-of-algorithms

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84495/computational-complexity-of-least-square-regression-operation) algorithmic analysis of least squares regression, we throw away big-$O$ terms that will be dominated by the biggest, and keep only the dominant term.

On the other hand, in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4808403/computational-complexity-of-truncation/4814355#4814355) algorithmic analysis of matrix multiplication followed by truncation, the matrix multiplication dominates the truncation, but we keep the lesser big-O term, and the final result is the product of both.

Why is this? When should we throw away non-dominating terms, and when should we keep them?

Answer (score 1):

We always could throw away non-dominating terms.

For the second Q, it's the same.

Given that the truncation operator :$ℝ^→ℝ^$ by $()=max\{min\{,\},0\}$, it's reasonable to deduce that it takes $O(m)$.

Matrix multiplication takes $O(m n)$, and then we get a new vector Ay, applying T on it takes another O(m).

Hence, it takes O(mn+m) =  O(mn) in total, throwing away the non-dominating term.

(Exception is that it's done in designated hardware, where it could be parallelized, as low as O(1) for truncation operator.)

Answer (score 0):

In the latter, $T$ requires $O(m)$ work for **each** of the $O(mn)$ entries of $A\bf y$. That’s why they are multiplied.

Comment: As it happens, this answer is wrong.  The $T$ defined in the link in the question only takes $O(1)$ work for each entry of $Ay$.  It is not applied to each entry of $A$, but to each entry of $Ay$.   The answer on Math.SE claiming it takes $O(m^2n)$ time is also wrong.

Comment: @D.W., okay. Of course, in that case  the running time **is** still a product ;-)